# Is it possible to create a SSTP (VPN over SSL) without Windows Server?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, sstp

Does anyone know if is possible to create an SSTP VPN avaiblabe on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008 with SP1 using Windows 7 as a Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows 7 can act as a (small) VPN server, but only using the PPTP and L2TP protocols.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I want a VPN over SLL connection, my options here is OpenVPN or what? (When I create and Incoming Connection on Windows 7 is PPTP?)

Comment: For free or low cost, I think OpenVPN is your only option.  If you have a budget, you can get SSL VPN from a variety of vendors including Cisco and Juniper.

Answer (score 1):

You need the NPAS server Role with the RRAS role service to create a SSTP VPN server, so no, you can't use Windows 7 to do so.